# Decimal/Int Data Types in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to enter a value which can be either decimal or int. What is the data type I need to set for the column in the database?

Comment: Which SQL Engine you are using?

Comment: @Radu, I used decimal(3,2). But when I tried to insert the value 12, it gives the error: "Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @MultiThreader, it is SQL 2008.

Comment: Try decimal(4,2). Btw how many didgit int value you can have?

Comment: @Multithreader, there's no limit for the length.

Comment: `Decimal(3,2)` means *three digits all in all, two of which being after the decimal separator.* So you can only enter one digit before the comma. Usually you'd use something like `DECIMAL(18,3)` or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

considering you have two different value types it may be more beneficial to have to NULLable columns with different data type. If you have like 100-1000 rows in a table it's not an issue and you can go with big `DECIMAL(18,3)` or even `DECIMAL(38,10)` as needed and convert everything to this big format. 
However if you hit billions of rows you should keep in mind that while standard `INT` is only 4 bytes big, the smallest `DECIMAL` is 5 bytes and that's for precision under 10. For wider values it can easily grow into 9 bytes or more, more than doubling storage space used.